# How to insert a specify row in mysql?

Tags: mysql

Suppose I have a table `t1` like

```
mysql> select * from t1;
+------+-------+------+
| id   | level | gap  |
+------+-------+------+
|    1 |     6 |   50 |
|    1 |     5 |   10 |
|    2 |     5 |   12 |
|    2 |     5 |   10 |
|    3 |     8 |    4 |
|    3 |     9 |    1 |
|    3 |     9 |    3 |
|    3 |     7 |    2 |
+------+-------+------+
```

I want to insert a row `(3,6,7)` into here.I mean it is below in first 5 row.

[image]

Is it possible in mysql?

Comment: Rows in an RDBMS represent unordered sets, so the question is meaningless

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just do

```
INSERT INTO t1 (id, level,gap) VALUES (3,6,7)
```

Records in a table do not have a *prescribed* order. The order has to be defined during a `SELECT` by supplying a suitable `ORDER BY` clause.

So, if you want the new record to be listed in 5th position use `ORDER BY id, level`.

Comment: My be the "TABLE" should be omitted.Anyway,thanks a lot.  :)

Comment: Hey @yode, of course, you are right! Just corrected my answer accordingly. Thanks for pointing it out!